# In $\triangle ABC$, if the angles are in an A.P and $b:c=\sqrt{3}:\sqrt{2}$, compute $\angle A$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

As title suggests, we have a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with angles in an arithmetic progression, and sides $b$ and $c$ in a ratio of $\sqrt{3}:\sqrt{2}$. This is a problem I saw from a mathematics textbook in India. While I don't exactly remember the name I do know it was for grade 11-12.

I'm posting this here to see what the easiest possible way could be to solve it. I'm going to share my own approach here, please share your own as well as pointing out any flaws in mine if you spot any:

Here's my method:

So, since we know that $\angle A, \angle B$ and $\angle C$ are in arithmetic progression, we can say that the arithmetic mean between $A$ and $C$ is $B$:

$$B=\frac{A+C}{2}$$

$$2B=A+C$$

$$3B=A+B+C$$

$$3B=180^\circ$$

$$\angle B=60^\circ$$

Now we know that:

$$\frac{b}{\sin{B}}=\frac{c}{\sin{C}}$$

$$\frac{c}{b}=\frac{\sin{C}}{\sin{B}}$$

$$\sin{C}=\sin{B}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

$$\sin{C}=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)$$

$$\sin{C}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Therefore, $\angle C=45^\circ$ and thus, $\angle A=180^\circ-45^\circ-60^\circ=75^\circ.$

Comment: I don't know if "angles in an arithmetic progression" necessarily means $2B=A+C$. There is a triangle satisfying $2A=B+C$ where $C\lt A=60^\circ\lt B$ are in an arithmetic progression.

Comment: But not only is that a trivial (although correct) case, but if that was what was intended, then this question wouldn't even be asked. @mathlove

Comment: It is very natural *for me* to conclude that the answer for your question is $A=75^\circ, 60^\circ$. Note that "trivial" does not mean that you can ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since angles are in an arithmetic progression, $(\angle B - \alpha) + \angle B + (\angle B +\alpha) =180^\circ$ then $\angle B= 60^\circ$

Let's say $b=\sqrt3, c=\sqrt2$.

Draw $AH \perp BC$ then $\angle BAH=30^\circ$and $AH=\frac{\sqrt6}{2}$.

Then in $\triangle AHC$, $HC=\frac{\sqrt6}{2}$ (Pytagorean theorem) and $AH=HC=\frac{\sqrt6}{2}$.

$\angle C = \angle CAH = 45^\circ$.

$\angle A = 30^\circ+ 45^\circ=75^\circ$.

Comment: Where does he claim that the sides are in AP? @Piquito

Comment: I "read" sides instead of angles. You are right @Goku. Thank you. (I add an upvote for Lion Heart).